# Is there a way to grab the current select box option's value without submitting?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, input

I'm trying to build some functionality for a project, but I'm stuck with this:

**I want to grab the value from a select box option, and use it in my php script**

The thing is, I need to grab the currently selected option without the user having to post the data. So I suspect there is a little bit of ajax required here, which I am completely new to.

I'll give you an example to make things clearer:

```
        <select>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        </select>
```

- User is presented with a select box
- User chooses 'Belarus' from the drop-down
- I need to be able to take the value 'Belarus' and assign it to a variable in php

I have no idea how to do this without them submitting the form.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: it should $('#selectboxid').val() right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send data to your PHP script using AJAX:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != '') {
        $.get('path/to/script.php', {'select-name' : val}, function (serverResponse) {
            //this is the callback for this AJAX request, the server has handled the request and anything output by your PHP script will be available in the `serverResponse` variable
        });
    }
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `ajax` to partially submit data to the server. Try this

```
$.ajax({
   url: "urlOfThePage",
   type: "POST",//Based on your requirement you can set it to GET/PUT etc
   data: {
      paramName: $("select").val();//this will get the selected value from the dropdown
   },
   sucess: function(){
     alert("Data submitted");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="my-select">
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select>
```

and use jquery to get the value and pass it to the server:

```
var value = $("#my-select").val();
$.get('myscript.php', { select_value: value });
```